# how to import an extension function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

this is the function i'm trying to import https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density#(androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpRect).toRect()

here is my code

```
    val cardWidth = 180f.dp
    val cardHeight = 270f.dp
    val fullHeight = 296f.dp 
    val focusRect = DpRect(0f.dp, 0f.dp, cardWidth, fullHeight).toRect()
```

i have tried importing like

```
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density.toRect
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.toRect
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.DpRect.toRect
```

but non of them works.

Comment: Have you tried getting your IDE to do the import? For example, in IntelliJ, move the cursor to the `focusRect` line, immediately after the last `.`, then invoke the code completion (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+Space). The relevant function should appear in the resulting list, and selecting it should add the import as well as inserting its name. — Or if it's _not_ shown in the list, then you can't call it there, e.g. because the receiver is the wrong type, or that library isn't in your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

That's an extension function *inside a `Density` object*, a member function - you need to run it within that context. You can't just import it and use it anywhere, because it's internal to that object. (See the comment in [the first example here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members).)

So you need to do something like this:

```
val focusRect = Density(density = 2f).run {
    DpRect(0f.dp, 0f.dp, cardWidth, fullHeight).toRect()
}
```

which, import limitations aside, makes sense - how can you convert *dp* values to *px* values if you haven't defined the density involved? You can see how it works in [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui-unit/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/unit/Density.kt;l=134;drc=6f98648f72464dde86ec533761266ae58c720c51):

```
fun DpRect.toRect(): Rect {
    return Rect(
        left.toPx(),
        top.toPx(),
        right.toPx(),
        bottom.toPx()
    )
}

fun Dp.toPx(): Float = value * density
```

where `density` is a property on the `Density` object, the one we passed in as a parameter. Basically you can create a `Density` and use it to perform conversions based on that density. The extension functions don't make sense outside of that context, right?